# Add ActionBar items on my MasterDetailFlow?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, master-detail

My main activity on my Android app is a MasterDetailFlow activity, and I don't know how to add items to the ActionBar. I've used this code from the developer website:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
</menu>
```

My XML files in `res/layout` are as follows:

- activity_item_detail.xml
- activity_item_list.xml
- activity_item_twopane.xml
- fragment_item_detail.xml

When I add the above XML code to any of them I get an error: `The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.`

None of the files start with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Comment: It's worth carefully reading these two pages, which answer all your questions: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the menu in a separate XML file and then inflate it. The recommended way to  do it is to create a folder 'menu' and place the menu file inside it.

Now you need to create an `OptionsMenu`:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        final MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.myMenu, menu); // inflating the menu
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Create an `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch(id) {
            case android.R.id.menu_settings:
               // do whatever you want
                break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: would that folder be under `res/layout/menu` or `res/menu`?